# NSTimer selector method not getting accessed from another class

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, selector, nstimer

I have one class (Sample) defined in sample.m where I have the following methods:

```
-(NSInteger)refreshValue:(id)sender{
//Do some thing here and return value.
  NSLog(@"Print something here");
  return something;
}

-(IBAction)monitorValue:(id)sender {
   NSLog(@"In here");
    timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval: 1
                 target: self
                     selector: @selector(refreshValue:)
                 userInfo: nil
             repeats: YES];

}
```

Now I have another class, test.m. From test.m, I do this:

```
Sample *test = [Sample alloc]
[test monitorValue:(id)sender]
```

WHen I run this code, I can see the monitor value method get called. But the refreshValue method never gets called from within monitorValue, which is what I want. If I call monitorValue from sample.m, then everything works. It just does not work when called from a different object.

Any ideas ? Thanks.

Comment: not sure if it'll help but change the parameter to `scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval` from `1` to `1.0f` (it's a NSTimeInterval -- or double -- value).  Also, are you starting up a brand new timer *every* time that button is touched?  You should probably check to see that `timer` is not null.

Comment: Fixed it with:

       [test performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(monitorValue:) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];

Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Your timer callback method signature is not correct. Per the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/Reference/NSTimer.html), it should be:

```
- (void)timerFireMethod:(NSTimer*)theTimer
```

Comment: This is not the reason. Timers just invoke the selector, they don't care what method's signature is. This particular `refreshValue:` signature is perfectly OK for being called by timer without crashing or anything. The real cause of problem must be somewhere else.